# jQuery - Hiding One Div & Showing Multiple Other Divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

http://jsfiddle.net/cEJtA/

```
$(function () {

    $(".div1, .div2").hide();
    
    $(".link1, .link2").bind("click", function () {

      $(".div1, .div2").hide();        
        
      if ($(this).attr("class") == "link1")
      {
        $(".div1").show();
      }
      else 
      { 
        $(".div2").show();
      }
    });

});
```

Can anyone please help with this code.

I want 5 divs that work based on the link that's clicked, so there are 5 divs either shown/hidden.

I can do everything except the if/else statement for more divs - any help please?

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: are they being injected dynamically ? well, you can just pass the id/class to click handlers and use that to toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you can add a data attribute on the class and use that to toggle the targeted div element.

```js
$(function () {

    $(".div1, .div2,.div4, .div3, .div5").hide();
    
    $("a").bind("click", function () {
       $(".div1, .div2,.div4, .div3, .div5").hide();
       var target = $(this).data("target");
       $("."+target).toggle();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

    <a href="#" class="link1" data-target="div1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link2" data-target="div2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="link3" data-target="div3">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="link4" data-target="div4">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="link5" data-target="div5">Link 5</a>
    
    
    <div class="div1">I'm div1</div>
    <div class="div2">I'm div2</div>
    <div class="div3">I'm div3</div>
    <div class="div4">I'm div4</div>
    <div class="div5">I'm div5</div>
    
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

you could also get the current element's class, parse it and generate div class name off of it and use that to show/hide things. e-g
link1 => div1 (replace link with div)

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly - @Muhammad Usman. Sorry to ask a further question, but is there a way to alternatively have Link 1/Div 1 on display as a default? So when your page loads it is on Div 1, then by clicked 2, 3, 4 or 5 behaves the same was as it currently does? Thanks very much again.

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment, I took the .div1 out of the jQuery second line and it's working fine so that'll do.

Comment: Unless you can think of any possible issues I might encounter using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<html>
<body>

    <a href="#" class="link1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="link2">Link 2</a>
    
    <div id="link1" class="commonDiv">I'm div1</div>
    <div id="link2" class="commonDiv">I'm div2</div>
    
    
</body>
</html>


$(function () {

    $(".commonDiv").hide();
    
    $(".link1, .link2").bind("click", function () {

      $(".commonDiv").hide(); 
      
      var id = $(this).attr("class");
      
      $('#' + id).show();
    });

});
```